# Query multiple Firestore Collections for same field

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am looking to find documents across several Collections where they have documents with no description field, I want to avoid looping but want to find the most efficient way of doing this. This code works in one collection.

```
            firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection('creators') // ### Would need to loop for 4 others like this #####
            .where('description', '==', '')
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) => {
                if (snapshot.empty) {
                    console.log('No matching documents.')
                    return
                }

                snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data())
                })
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log('Error getting documents', err)
            })
```

Comment: What's wrong with looping?

Comment: I suppose I am thinking it is more efficient to send a bundle of work to Firebase, it chunks through it and sends me the results rather than 5 requests. Might not be a problem doing that though.

Comment: will this repeat often? Perhaps storing the superposition state that you need (maintaining the updates on the cost of the read).

Comment: yes, it is for a Dashboard of a SaaS product. It is checking the status of a bunch of collections and providing recommendations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to execute all the queries **in parallel**, as follows:

```
   const db = firebase.firestore();

   const q1 = db.collection('creators').where('description', '==', '...').get();
   const q2 = db.collection('xyz').where('description', '==', '...').get();

   return Promise.all([q1, q2])
   .then(snapshotsArray => {

       snapshotsArray.forEach(snap => {
            snap.forEach(doc => {
                console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data())
            })
       })

   })
```

---

You could simplify it as follows:

```
   const collectionNames = ['creators', 'klmn', 'opqr', 'stuv']
   const promises = collectionNames.map(x => db.collection(x).where('description', '==', '...').get());

   Promise.all(promises)
   .then(snapshotsArray => {

       snapshotsArray.forEach(snap => {
            snap.forEach(doc => {
                 console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data())
            })
       })

   })
```

As explained in the doc referred to above:

> The `Promise.all()` method returns a single Promise that fulfills when
>   all of the promises passed as an iterable have been fulfilled
>
> ...
>
> The returned promise is fulfilled with an array containing all the
>   values of the iterable passed as argument (also non-promise values).

---

### HOWEVER,

there is an important point to note, based on this sentence in your question: "find documents across several Collections where they have documents **with no description field**".

You cannot build a query in Firestore that will return document **without a given field**. The reason (indexing mechanism) is well explained in this official [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofux_4c94FI) .

On the other hand, you can query for a document with an empty field:

```
db.collection('creators').where('description', '==', '').get();
```

or with a field with `null` value:

```
db.collection('creators').where('description', '==', null).get();
```

Comment: The field will exist, just empty. Great explanation, thank you.